# Combine two regular expression rule in sed to remove unwanted characters from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to remove all non alphanumerical characters and non space characters and non dash non underscore characters

```
echo "$1" |sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]//g'
```

i want some thing like

```
echo "$1" |sed 's/[^\-\_a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]//g'
```

How can i mix two regex rules together?

sample input is:

```
a-b
a_b
ab
a..
a.b
a   b
a %b
a ^&n
```

I want this output:

```
a-b
a_b
ab
a
ab
a b
a b
a n
```

Comment: What's the issue with your 2nd regex?

Comment: please consider adding example inputs and current outputs. This looks like it should work, as is. Good luck.

Comment: my second regex give error as invalid range operator if I change it as this:

sed 's/[^\_[\-]a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]//g' no more errors but doesn't work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/[^-_a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]//g' file
```

```
$ cat file
a-b
a_b
ab
a..
a.b
a   b
a %b
a ^&n

$ sed 's/[^-_a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]//g' file
a-b
a_b
ab
a
ab
a   b
a b
a n
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/[^-_[:alnum:][:space:]]//g' file` would work too.